# Using a Console Application as a Screensaver

Tags: c++, console, screensaver

I have created a simple C++ program that continuously outputs cosine waves made out of `1`s and `0`s to the console.  Is there an easy way to use a console application as a screensaver, or do I have to dabble in the Windows API?